# Java: library to calculate the mean?

Tags: java

Is there a function in Jave to calculate the mean ?

I've tried by myself but I'm afraid that sum has too high value: 5 642 782 840

Can a integer be 5 642 782 840 in Java ? I don't think so...

```
for (int i = 0; i < timeValues.length; i++) {               
    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(timeValues[i]);
}
   time = Integer.toString(sum / timeValues.length);
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer` can hold values between -2.147.483.648 and 2.147.483.647.
`Long` can hold values between -9.223.372.036.854.775.808 and 9.223.372.036.854.775.807.

Thus a `long` would be suitable for your use case.

Another solution to do it without libraries would be to use `java.math.BigInteger` for your calculations. It supports even bigger numbers. At least if you don't use floating point values like `float` or `double`. Of what type are your values in the timeValues array?

If you want to use a library you may want to have a look at [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/). To be more precise: have a look at [DescriptiveStatistics](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html) and [SummaryStatistics](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/SummaryStatistics.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
//================================================= mean
public static double mean(double[] p) {
    double sum = 0;  // sum of all the elements
    for (int i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
        sum += p[i];
    }
    return sum / p.length;
}//end method mean
```

right off [this site](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-ex-mean.html)

after **googling once** `Java mean`

Answer (score 1):

Since java arrays are limited to using a 32 bit index, it is always safe for us `long` for computing the sum of an array of `int` or `Integer`, on the other hand, if you need to compute the sum or average of an array of `long` or a collection then you might want to use `java.math.BigInteger`

Chris has the generally correct answer, but since you appear to be using an array of strings

```
public static double meanOfStrings(String[] p) {
  long sum = 0;  // sum of all the elements
  for (int i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
     sum += Long.parseLong(p[i]);
  }
  return ((double) sum) / p.length;
}
```

Comment: If you need a precise result, `double` is no good choice because it only has 53 bits of precision, while you need approximately 63 bits of precision. Therefore, `long` is better suited, and it is probably faster, too.

Comment: @Roland illig You are correct that the sum produced by adding up a ton of doubles is going to be less accurate.  I have changed my text accordingly.  I still think though that returning a double is correct for averages.

Comment: Yes, for the return value `double` is generally the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

To build in @smas's solution

```
public static double mean(double[] m) {
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    sum += (double)m[i]/ (double)m.length;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

By dividing along the way, we can avoid the overflow issues.

Answer (score 0):

For simple use:

```
public static double mean(double[] m) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        sum += m[i];
    }
    return sum / m.length;
}
```

For advanced use try some library:
Have look at [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/)

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what other people say, I'm pretty sure a long can hold that high numbers.