# Java library/data structure that computes average of elements in list?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have a list of doubles and want to find the average. 
I can do it by a simple for loop, but doing this everytime does not make sense. Writing a static method will also be a waste if this functionality already exists in some library.

The [TDoubleArrayList](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/TDoubleArrayList.html) in the trove collection provides methods like min(), max(), binarySearch() etc. but not average() or sum().

The [DoubleArrayList](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/list/DoubleArrayList.html) in the Colt library provides methods like shuffle() but not sum() or average.

The fastutil [DoubleArrayList](http://fastutil.dsi.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/doubles/DoubleArrayList.html) also does not provide sum() or average().

Is there some library which provides sum() or average()?

Comment: I will not be happy to depend on a third-party library for such a simple functionality...

Comment: @Peter: If you are already using, say fastutil, then why not?

Comment: @athena - If you are already using a library, which provides it - then OK. But to depend on a library only for finding an average...

Comment: @Peter: Yes, I agree. But I am already using fastutil and trove. And I was surprised that neither fastutil not trove provide this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: library to calculate the mean ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492553/java-library-to-calculate-the-mean)

Comment: Colt provides BOTH average (mean  http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/jet/stat/Descriptive.html#mean(cern.colt.list.DoubleArrayList) and sum http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/jet/stat/Descriptive.html#sum(cern.colt.list.DoubleArrayList)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [Colt Library](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/), it's used at Cern for numerical and mathematical computation, and has numerous libraries for performing statistical methods on arrays and matrices. (It doesn't operate directly on Java primitive arrays, you have to use their *[DoubleArrayList](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/jet/stat/Descriptive.html#mean%28cern.colt.list.DoubleArrayList%29)* implementation)

- [Descriptive.mean(DoubleArrayList)](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/jet/stat/Descriptive.html#mean%28cern.colt.list.DoubleArrayList%29)
- [Descriptive.sum(DoubleArrayList)](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/jet/stat/Descriptive.html#sum%28cern.colt.list.DoubleArrayList%29)

Comment: Athena stated *in the question* that Colt doesn't have what's needed.

Comment: And you might want to wait more than thirty seconds before moaning about the lack of comment on a downvote!

Comment: It has _mean_ http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/jet/stat/Descriptive.html#mean(cern.colt.list.DoubleArrayList) and I bet there's a total or sum in there too.

Comment: And it has _sum_ http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/jet/stat/Descriptive.html#sum(cern.colt.list.DoubleArrayList)

Comment: As i was saying, excellent answer, +1. I've taken the liberty of adding big obvious links to the methods in question.

Comment: Yes, in retrospect explicit links in the answer would have been better ;-)

Answer (score 4):

[Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/) gives you what you want. Take a look at [StatUtils.mean(double[] values)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/StatUtils.html#mean%28double%5b%5d%29) and  [StatUtils.sum(double[] values)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/StatUtils.html#sum%28double%5b%5d%29).

Answer (score 0):

I'm only aware of [`MathTool`](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/1.4/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/MathTool.html) from [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) that has `getAverage()` and `getTotal()`. These take an array and not a list however. Is it honestly worth finding a library just for a few very simple methods? I appreciate that you're trying to leverage existing code. Yet if you can't easily find something and it's trivial to write and test, I'd suggest just writing it yourself. Create a few static methods and reuse those throughout your code, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong with writing static methods and reusing them. I was concerned that I was missing something because I am already using fastutil and trove, and they don't provide sum() or average() while providing methods like min() and max() and shuffle() etc.